# Sorted list on date with multipart identifier error

Tags: sql

```
"Project nr"    "Task"                "Task deadline"  "Task Type Production"

456             packed                1 april 2013      Packed
456             Leave production      3 april 2013      Leave Production
456             Flight date           9 april 2013      Flight Date
123             packed                1 april 2013      Packed
123             Leave production      6 april 2013      Leave Production
123             Flight date           9 april 2013      Flight Date
789             packed                1 april 2013      Packed
789             Leave production      9 april 2013      Leave Production
789             Flight date           9 april 2013      Flight Date
```

I need a list like above I want to sort on the date of 'Leave production' The project nr has to stay ingroups of 3 like the list above.

I already have this SQL. The list is working but  the sort is not working. The error is:  The multi-part identifier "task.[task deadline]" could not be bound.
How do I get is sorted?

```
    SELECT  [Project nr], Task, TaskDate
    FROM    (
    SELECT   MSP_EpmProject_UserView.[Project nr]
            ,MAX(CASE   WHEN [Task Type Production] = 'Packed' 
                        THEN [Task deadline] 
                    END) AS Packed
            ,MAX(CASE   WHEN [Task Type Production] = 'Leave Production' 
                        THEN [Task deadline]
                    END) AS [Leave Production]
            ,MAX(CASE   WHEN [Task Type Production] = 'Flight Date' 
                        THEN [Task deadline]
                    END) AS [Flight Date]
    FROM    MSP_EpmProject_UserView 
            LEFT JOIN MSP_EpmTask_UserView 
                ON MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectUID = MSP_EpmTask_UserView.ProjectUID 
            LEFT JOIN MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView 
                ON MSP_EpmTask_UserView.TaskUID = MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.TaskUID 
            LEFT JOIN MSP_EpmResource_UserView 
                ON MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.ResourceUID = MSP_EpmResource_UserView.ResourceUID 
    WHERE (MSP_EpmTask_UserView.TaskIsProjectSummary = 0) 
    GROUP BY MSP_EpmProject_UserView.[Project nr]
    ) data
    UNPIVOT
    (
      TaskDate
      for [Task] in ([Pack],[Leave Production],[Flight Date])
    ) piv
    ORDER BY    data.[Task deadline]
```

This is the result with ORDER BY commented out. I would like a result as above also with the fields without date.

```
Project Nr     Task             TaskDate
0053           Packed           2013-02-05 17:00:00.000
0053           Leave Production 2011-04-26 17:00:00.000
0053           Flight Date      2011-04-22 17:00:00.000
0071           Leave Production 2011-06-24 17:00:00.000
0081           Leave Production 2012-03-09 17:00:00.000
0081-01        Leave Production 2012-03-09 17:00:00.000
```

Comment: name of the column is Task and you are using [Task Deadline], in your dynamic table Data the column is named as Task so use that name

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have a table/view/CTE that looks like the initial table in your question.  Use a window function to get the value for all the same "Project nr"s, then do the sort:

```
select "Project nr", "Task", "Task deadline", "Task Type Production"
from (select t.*,
             MAX(case when task = 'Leave Production' then "Task deadline" end) over (partition by "Project nr") as lpdl
      from t
     ) t
order by lpdl, 1
```